# How to prove that $(\mathbb{Q},d_p)$ is not complete?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, metric-spaces, p-adic-number-theory

How do we prove that the metric space $(\mathbb{Q},d_p)$, with $d_p$ the $p$-adic distance, is not complete ?
Can anyone construct a Cauchy sequence that does not converge?
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/921022/4280

Comment: There is an example on page 3 of [these notes](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~jat58/all.pdf)

Comment: see example $2.3.17$ in [this](https://dusolution.files.wordpress.com/2015/07/s-kumaresan-topology-of-metric-spaces-alpha-science-international-ltd-2005.pdf) book!

Answer (score 2):

**Example.** The series
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty p^{k!}
$$
represents an irrational $p$-adic number.

More generally, consider the $p$-adic expansion
$$
x = \sum_{j=n}^\infty s_j p^j
$$
where each $s_j \in \{0,1,.\dots,p-1\}$.  Then $x$ is rational if and only if the sequence $s_j$ is eventually periodic.  For the proof, follow the usual proof for rationality of base $10$ decimals, with appropriate easy changes.